# Removing Struct object from list using remove method in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to use remove method from list on struct object to remove it. This is my struct:

```
typedef struct pair{
  int x;
  int y;
} PAIR;
```

And this is code where i use it and where the error occurs:

```
list<PAIR> openSet;
PAIR pair;
pair.x = xStart;
pair.y = yStart;
openSet.push_front(pair);

PAIR current;
for(PAIR p : openSet){
    if(fScores[p.x * dim + p.y] < maxVal){
         maxVal = fScores[p.x * dim + p.y];
         current = p;
    }
}

openSet.remove(current);
```

Error that i am getting is this:

```
 no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘pair’ and ‘const value_type’ {aka ‘const pair’})
```

Can you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: your `maxVal` seems to be set to the minimum...

Comment: Stupid C++ trick: An extra decade-or-so of compiler know-how that wasn't around for the development of C allows C++ to `struct PAIR{ int x; int y; };` and get rid of the `typedef`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use `std::list::remove()`, elements have to be comparable for equality.  Implement an `operator==` for your struct, eg:

```cpp
typedef struct pair{
  int x;
  int y;

  bool operator==(const pair &rhs) const {
    return x == rhs.x && y == rhs.y;
  }
} PAIR;
```

Otherwise, use `std::find_if()` and `std::list::erase()`:

```cpp
auto iter = std::find_if(openSet.begin(), openSet.end(),
  [&](const PAIR &p){ return p.x == current.x && p.y == current.y; }
);
if (iter != openSet.end()) {
  openSet.erase(iter);
}
```

Or, `std::list::remove_if()`:

```cpp
openSet.remove_if(
  [&](const PAIR &p){ return p.x == current.x && p.y == current.y; }
);
```

Or, change your loop to use iterators explicitly:

```cpp
list<PAIR>::iterator current = openSet.end();
for(auto iter = openSet.begin(); iter != openSet.end(); ++iter){
    PAIR &p = *iter;
    if (fScores[p.x * dim + p.y] < maxVal){
         maxVal = fScores[p.x * dim + p.y];
         current = iter;
    }
}

if (current != openSet.end()) {
    openSet.erase(current);
}
```

Comment: Or store an iterator instead of a copy of the item to be removed

Comment: That helped. Thank you very much.